# How to right justify a xaml grid

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, xaml

HI This view is needs to be right justified, currently is left justified, which command needed to make it right just.?

```
<GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Unit}"
                                Header="Nursing Unit"
                                Width="70" />
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Day}"
                                Header="Day"
                                Width="55" />
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Eve}"
                                Header="Eve"
                                Width="55" />
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Night}"
                                Header="Night"
                                Width="55" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the Grid property FlowDirection to "RightToLeft".

Comment: I entered this it does it but it re-orders the cols as well, i just wanted right justified within the column,<UserControl x:Class="OPTFDashboard.Common.Modules.MissedMedications.Views.MedicineTileView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:vc="clr-namespace:Visifire.Charts;assembly=WPFVisifire.Charts"
             FlowDirection="RightToLeft"
             Template="{StaticResource TileControlTemplateNew}">